# Making a javascript function async with callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Previously I had

```
 MyClass.prototype.method1 = function(data1) {
    return this.data111.push(data1);
  };

 MyClass.prototype.method2 = function(i) {
    var data = this.method1(i);
    if (data.condition1 != null) {
      data.onEvent1(this);
    }
    return $(data.element).someMethod123("data123");
  };

 MyClass.prototype.method3 = function() {
    var data1 = this.method1(this._data1);
    return this.someMethod123(step.data1);
  };

MyClass.prototype.ended = function() {
    return !!this.getState("end");
  };


MyClass.prototype.getState = function(key) {
    var value = $.cookie(key);
    this._options.afterGetState(key, value);
    return value;
  };
```

How do I make async using callback functions? I guess it should be so:

```
 MyClass.prototype.method1 = function(data1, callback) {
    if(callback){
      callback(this.data111.push(data1));
    }
    else{
      return this.data111.push(data1);
   }
  };

 MyClass.prototype.method2 = function(i, callback) {

    var data = this.method1(i);
    if (data.condition1 != null) {
      data.onEvent1(this);
    }
    if(callback){
      callback($(data.element).someMethod123("data123"));
    }
    else{
     return $(data.element).someMethod123("data123");
    }
  };

 MyClass.prototype.method3 = function(callback) {
    var data1 = this.method1(this._data1);
     if(callback){
      callback(this.someMethod123(step.data1));
    }
    else{
       return this.someMethod123(step.data1);
    }
  };

MyClass.prototype.ended = function(callback) {
    if(callback){
       callback(!!this.getState("end", /*what should be here and what should it does?*/));
    }
  };


  MyClass.prototype.getState = function(key, callback) { 
    var oldThis = this;
    setTimeout(function(){ 
                    value = $.cookie(key);
                    callback(value, oldThis); 
                    oldThis._options.afterGetState(key, value);
                  },
              0);
  };
```

I definitely have missed something because I never used async functions in javascript before. So it that?

And, as I understood, to make a functions async, I basically should add one more parameter as a callback function and get rid of return, should not I?

Comment: I don't see why those functions would need to become async?

Comment: because of ajax, it's not shown here.

Comment: But not all of these methods do ajax, do they? Please show it in your code where you use ajax (no need for actual code, but a simple function `ajax(…, callback)`)

Comment: @Bergi, instead of `setTimeout` in `getState` there will be ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass on the callback:

```
MyClass.prototype.ended = function(callback) {
    this.getState("end", callback);
};
```

You should do this in your other functions too and I'd suggest to stick to one interface. I.e. either return the value directly (if possible) or use callbacks.

Comment: For instance, if I call somewhere `if(this.ended(/* what should I do here?*/)) { .... }`, how do I handle it?

Comment: Since `.ended` does not return a value, you would call the function this `this.ended(function(result) { /* do something with result*/ });`. The way you write your code changes when you use callbacks.

Comment: it does return the value, look at my first example.

Comment: Yes, if you don't use callbacks it does. But not when you use callbacks... did you even see my code? ;) You cannot return a value form a function which calls a function that needs a callback and is async. If you use callbacks, you have to use them all the way through.

Comment: Can I return value from this code: `setTimeout(function(){ 
                    value = $.cookie(key);
                    callback(value, oldThis); 
                    return oldThis._options.afterGetState(key, value);
                  },
              0);` ?

Comment: @Alan: No... the value is returned to whatever calls your callback, which is not your code. The return value is just lost. Maybe you find this question/answer helpful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196.

Comment: did ask that question and answer yourself?

Comment: Yes, because it's such a common question that needed an extensive explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Only those methods that do asynchronous tasks need callback style. There is no reason to use it for `method1`, `method2` and `method3`.

`getState` now is the actual asynchronous method. Using ajax/setTimeout/whatever is quite obvious in here. Yet, I can spot one mistake: The `callback` call should always be the last statement, just as you won't do anything after a `return` statement. Even though you can, better call back *after* setting the internal options object:

```
                …
                oldThis._options.afterGetState(key, value);
                callback(value, oldThis);
```

Now, the `ended` method. Since it uses the async `getState`, it will become asynchronous itself and you need to use callback style (notice that `getState()` will not return the value). So you will call `getState`, and when that calls back you will transform the result and pass it to your own callback:

```
MyClass.prototype.ended = function(callback) {
    this.getState("end", function ownCallback(state) {
        var result = !!state; // or whatever you need to do
        callback(result);
    });
};
// and if you don't need to do anything with the result, you can leave out ownCallback:
MyClass.prototype.ended = function(callback) {
    this.getState("end", callback);
};
```

Comment: Great explanation! why is it better to raise the "event" `afterGetState` before callback? I won't work properly because it will be raised before the state has been gotten.

Comment: <<Only those methods that do asynchronous tasks need callback style. There is no reason to use it for method1, method2 and method3.>> Why did you add `callback` parameter for `MyClass.prototype.ended = function(callback)` then? I only want to do `return !!this.getState("end");` there, how can I do that?

Comment: @AlanDert: Oh, it's an event? Then it might be OK. However, the callback function is quite like an event handler, and handlers should in general not depend on each other.

Comment: @AlanDert: Why `ended` has a callback? Because it is asynchronous - it uses the async `getState`!

Comment: It's clear now. So what if I want to call `this.ended(/*....*/)`, what should put there as a callback parameter?